# Import .ics-file into google calendar on android device

Tags: android, import, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I've got an android application which manages and display event like data out of a local SQLite database.

I would like to offer my customers the option to convert the data from the database to an .ics-file and import that file into a calendar.

I know how to create and store a valid .ics-file out of my database.

My problem is to import that file into the google or any other calendar.
I don't want to create a custom local calendar, I simply want to "open" the ics-file so that the user can choose a calendar or let the data import directly.

User Interaction -> .ics-file creation -> import of all events into the calendar

Any advice? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago. I found how to export individual tasks or events to Google Calendar. Check whole information [here](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar-3850276.htm)

I quote the way to add a event to the calendar from the link above:

> To add an entry to a specific calendar, we need to configure a
>   calendar entry to insert using the ContentValues as follows:
>
> ```
> ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
> ```
>
> Each event needs to be tied to a specific Calendar, so the first thing
>   you're going to want to set is the identifier of the Calendar to
>   insert this event into:
>
> ```
> event.put("calendar_id", calId);
> ```
>
> We then set some of the basic information about the event, including
>   String fields such as the event title, description and location.
>
> ```
> event.put("title", "Event Title");
> event.put("description", "Event Desc");
> event.put("eventLocation", "Event Location");
> ```
>
> There are a number of different options for configuring the time and
>   date of an event.
>
> We can set the event start and end information as follows:
>
> ```
> long startTime = START_TIME_MS;
> long endTime = END_TIME_MS;
> event.put("dtstart", startTime);
> event.put("dtend", endTime);
> ```
>
> If we are adding a birthday or holiday, we would set the entry to be
>   an all day event:
>
> ```
> event.put("allDay", 1);   // 0 for false, 1 for true
> ```
>
> This information is sufficient for most entries. However, there are a
>   number of other useful calendar entry attributes.
>
> For example, you can set the event status to tentative (0), confirmed
>   (1) or canceled (2):
>
> ```
> event.put("eventStatus", 1);
> ```
>
> You can control who can see this event by setting its visibility to
>   default (0), confidential (1), private (2), or public (3):
>
> ```
> event.put("visibility", 0);
> ```
>
> You can control whether an event consumes time (can have schedule
>   conflicts) on the calendar by setting its transparency to opaque (0)
>   or transparent (1).
>
> ```
> event.put("transparency", 0);
> ```
>
> You can control whether an event triggers a reminder alarm as follows:
>
> ```
> event.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true
> ```
>
> Once the calendar event is configured correctly, we're ready to use
>   the ContentResolver to insert the new calendar entry into the
>   appropriate Uri for calendar events:
>
> ```
>    Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");   Uri url =
>  getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
> ```
>
> The call to the insert() method contacts the Calendar content provider
>   and attempts to insert the entry into the appropriate user Calendar.
>   If you navigate to the Calendar application and launch it, you should
>   see your calendar entry in the appropriate Calendar. Since the
>   Calendar syncs, you will also see the Calendar entry online, if you're
>   using the Google Calendar on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [`import`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/import) service of Google Calendar API. It will require the `calendarId` which is explained on the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview) page.

The request body will contain the file you want to attach (though its limited to Google Drive, so you may want to look into [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) as well)

The `Events` resource `attachments` field description

> attachments[] list    File attachments for the event. Currently only Google Drive attachments are supported.
>   In order to modify attachments the supportsAttachments request parameter should be set to true.
>
> There can be at most 25 attachments per event,